# error installing php-pear on Debian Lenny

Tags: debian, debian-lenny, pear

```
[ps]$ sudo apt-get install php-pear
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php-pear
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
8 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0B/335kB of archives.
After this operation, 2408kB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  php-pear
Authentication warning overridden.
(Reading database ... 160671 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking php-pear (from .../php-pear_5.2.6.dfsg.1-1+lenny10_all.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/php-pear_5.2.6.dfsg.1-1+lenny10_a                                                                             ll.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite `/etc/pear/pear.conf', which is also in package ndn-php5-cg                                                                             i
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/php-pear_5.2.6.dfsg.1-1+lenny10_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't been able to establish what exactly the ndn-php5-cgi packge is or does, but it is certainly the reason why php-pear won't install. Either remove that package entirely or make sure that the debian installer can overwrite the /etc/pear/pear.conf file.  It's probably also a good idea to make a backup copy of that file so that you can figure out whether these two packages can actually live side by side.

Answer (score 1):

Well, throwing caution to the wind (thankfully on nothing critical) and apt-get remove of nun-php5-cgi which includes: ( ndn-apache22-php5 ndn-php5-cgi ndn-php5-xcache zendoptimizer) allowed me to the fully install php-pear with PECL with the almost the EXACT same error you were getting.  What these means down the road, I don't know, but it works for me on the experiment I'm running. (probably not the best programming technique).